# Picture automation in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2003

I have 2 sheets in excel. in 1st sheet I make 3 pictures i.e (Oval or square ) and rename those with A, B, C and also put in different colum A, B, C in different cell. and make it list in validation.
in 2nd sheet I use validation option for 1st sheet A, B, C.
Now I want if i select A picture should be display name as A same like for B and C.
how it will be happen, really i don't know please help me because I knew just basic of Excel.   [EMAIL SNIPPED].

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this can give you what you want:

Go to Tools>Macro>Macros and create a macro named ClickA, then change the macro code to this:

```
Sub ClickA()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Formula = "A"
End Sub
Sub ClickB()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Formula = "B"
End Sub
Sub ClickC()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Formula = "C"
End Sub
```

Now close the macro editor, rightclick each of the ovals or squares that you had and assign the corresponding macros to them.
Good luck!